# Measure tool QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and longish in the tooth, so please be kind.

I used the measure tool, and the lines measured show up in my project even with all my layers deselected.
I can find no additional data in the attribute tables of all the layers.

I have tried select features but to no avail.

Comment: Close the measure tool

Comment: Measure tool draws temporary lines onto the map canvas. They disappear when you click another tool.

Comment: neither of those seemed to work but thanks anyway.I started measure line, drew a line then managed to delete them all - result.

Comment: Many thanks - 'till next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure line will disappear when :

- you close the measure tool window or
- when you click on the "New" button of the measure tool window or
- When you select another tool.

It's independent of layer visibility.

[image]

See [This part of QGIS doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#measuring) to read more on measuring.

Comment: Be aware that after closing the measure tool, clicking the map canvas will re-open it, unless you have first selected another tool (such as pan or select).